# Commutative Diagrams and their relationship to induced homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology

Throughout my topology class my professor has used commutative diagrams on various occasions to prove results such as

1) There exists no antipode preserving, continuous, onto map, $f: S^2 \to S^1$

2) $[0,1] \setminus 0 \sim 1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

3) Prove that $S^2 \setminus (x,y,z) \sim (-x,-y,-z)$ is homeomorphic to the real projective plane.

The diagram of (1) looks like this,

$$\begin{array}
^{S^2} & \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} & S^1 \\
\downarrow{q_1} & & \downarrow{q_2} \\
S^2 \setminus \sim & \stackrel{F}{\longrightarrow} & S^1\setminus \sim
\end{array}
$$

where $S^2 \setminus \sim$ refers to $S^2 \setminus (x,y,z) \sim (-x,-y,-z)$ and $S^1 \setminus x \sim -x$

$f:S^2 \to S^1$ is such that $f(x)=-f(-x)$. To prove such a function does not exists we used the commutative diagram of the induced homomorphism.

$$\begin{array}
^\pi_1({S^2}) & \stackrel{f_*}{\longrightarrow} & \pi_1(S^1) \\
\downarrow{q_{1_*}} & & \downarrow{q_{2_*}} \\
S^2 \setminus \sim & \stackrel{F_*}{\longrightarrow} & S^1\setminus \sim
\end{array}
$$

and showed that an appropriate $F*$ does not exists.

$\textbf{Question}$ Why does the non-existense of $F_{*}$ imply that $f$ cannot exist?

Furthermore, what is meant by an appropriate $F_{*}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposition we wish to prove is that there does not exist a map $f\colon S^2\to S^1$ such that $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for all $x\in S^2$. In order to prove this, let us suppose that such an $f$ does exists. Given this, there must then also exist an $F\colon S^2/{\sim}\to S^1/{\sim}$ given by $F([x])=[f(x)]$. In order to see that $F$ is well defined we note that if $x'\in[x]$ then $x'$ is either $x$ or $-x$ by definition of $\sim$ and so the only other possible value of $F([-x])$ is $[f(-x)]$ but by the condition that $f$ satisfies, we know that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and so $F([-x])=[-f(x)]$ and again by the definition of $\sim$ (the one on $S^1$ this time) we know that $[-f(x)]=[f(x)]$. It follows that $F([-x])=[f(x)]=F([x])$ and so $F$ is well defined.

The fact that $F$ is continuous is a consequence of the universal property of quotient maps and the fact that we have the commutative diagram
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
   S^2    & \ra{f}       &    S^1     \\
  \da{q_1}     &              &  \da{q_2}               \\
   S^2/{\sim}       & \ras{F} &    S^1/{\sim}                        \\
\end{array}
$$ where $q_i$ is the appropriate quotient map.

So, given that $f$ exists with the required property, there must exist an $F$ which satisfies the above commutative square.

By applying the fundamental group functor to the above diagram of continuous maps, we get the following diagram

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
   \pi_1(S^2)    & \ra{f_*}       &    \pi_1(S^1)     \\
  \da{(q_1)_*}     &              &  \da{(q_2)_*}               \\
   \pi_1(S^2/{\sim})       & \ras{F_*} &    \pi_1(S^1/{\sim})                        \\
\end{array}
$$

and we note that $\pi_1(S^2/{\sim})\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $F_*$ is the zero map as this is the only homomorphism from a finite group into the integers. This means that no loop in $S^2/{\sim}$ is mapped to a non-trivial loop in $S^1$ under $F$. By considering the equator $A\cong S^1$ of $S^2$, we see that $(f|_A)_*\colon\pi_1(A)\to \pi_1(S^1)$ is not the zero map as $f|_A$ is antipode preserving, and $(q_2)_*$ is just the multiplication by $2$ map and so there exists some loop $\gamma$ living in $A\subset S^2$ which is mapped to a non-trivial loop in $S^1/{\sim}$. This means, by commutativity, that $q_1\circ\gamma$ is a loop in $S^2/{\sim}$ which is mapped to a non-trivial loop in $S^1/{\sim}$ - however this contradicts the fact that we said no such loop can exist.

It follows that we have made a false assumption somewhere. The only assumption made was that $f$ with the required properties exists. It follows such an $f$ can not exist and so we are done.

Comment: If $g\colon S^1\to S^1$ is an antipode preserving map then it is not null-homotopic - Theorem 1.4.12 [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/tholden/CourseNotes/TopologyII.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. However, I cannot see how that proof shows that $\exists$ $\alpha \in S^1$, such that $f(\alpha)\neq y_0$. Where $\alpha$ is a loops starting at $x_0$ and $y_0=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Sorry your notation is a bit garbled. Is $\alpha$ a point in $S^1$ or a loop?